# C# MVC - Erro após publish no VS015. 404 Not Found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2015, iis

Eu fiz um "Publish" pelo VS2015 do tipo Web MVC, mas no "Publish Method" coloquei "File System". O problema é que publiquei no IIS e roda as views, mas quando clico nos botões ele não acha os métodos. Como se não tivesse Controller. O que faço?

Quando eu chamo (http://localhost/Produtos/ToViewCriar), dá isso:

Erro HTTP 404.0 - Not Found
O recurso que você está procurando foi removido, teve o seu nome alterado ou está temporariamente indisponível.

PS: Fiz o publish em outra máquina, mas o IIS fiz na própria

Comment: Quando você chama na própria maquina antes do publish funciona?

Comment: O projeto está em MVC5? Qual a versão do IIS?

Comment: @Paz, funciona sim, muito bem quando uso no VS2015

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, eu usei o VS2015, acrddito que seja a última versão do MVC. E o IIS é o 10.0

Comment: Seu VS está atualizado (Tools / Extensions and Updates)?

Answer (score 1):

Bem, na verdade eu resolvi o problema. É que eu não sabia como rodar o programa do ASP.NET com um "Publish" no "File System".

Eu usei o programa "WebMatrix" pra poder rodá-lo e funcionou muito bem.

Grato a todos.